# Drupal 7 Create Content -> Page viewable by admin only

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to create a page on my Drupal 7 website for admins only. It's a reporting page. I do NOT want non-admins to be able to access this page whatsoever. I installed the simpleaccess module and have had no luck with it -- I can't figure out how to set permissions for admins only. I DO have an admin role on my website and some users are assigned to it. I'm up for any options (other modules or the simplest, cleanest solution). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your current template.php
add

```
    function bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
      if($variables['nid'] == nid){
        global $user;
        if (!in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
          drupal_access_denied();
        }
      }
    }
```

Replace nid with your page nid.
Replace "bartik_" with your template name.
Clear Cache.